# Creating the Butterfly curve with arrays

Tags: javascript

I have two questions, the first being how do I access the indexes within my array separately, because my console.log of [n][0] results in two values - x and y. Secondly, for the butterfly curve, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butterfly_curve_%28transcendental%29, how would I determine the values of t? and reiterate through a certain minimum and maximum. In need of logic support.

Here's my progress so far.

```
/*function drawButterFly(n){
    c.beginPath();
    console.log(n[2])
    for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
        if (i === 0) {
            c.moveTo();
        } else {
            c.lineTo();
        }
        c.stroke();

    }

}*/

function butterFly() {
    var r = 5;
    var N = 3;
    var value = [];
    for (var a = 0.2; a < 2*Math.PI; a = a + 0.1){
        value.push(a);
    }

    var t = value[Math.floor(Math.random()*value.length)];
    var cos = r*Math.cos(t)*( (Math.exp(Math.cos(t))) - (2*Math.cos(4*t)) - (Math.sin(t/12)^5) );
    var sin = r*Math.sin(t)*( (Math.exp(Math.cos(t))) - (2*Math.cos(4*t)) - (Math.sin(t/12)^5) );

    var n = [];
    for (var u = 0; u < N; u++){
        var x = sin * -u;
        var y = cos * -u;
        n.push([x,y]);
    }
    drawButterFly(n);
}
```

Comment: Usually, 1 question per question is adviced.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the Butterfly curve is given as a pair of parametric equations, meaning you increment `t` to get the next `(x, y)` points on your curve. In other words, your `t` is what you should be using in place of u in your code, and the range of values for `t` should be `0 .. 2*pi` as that's the range `sin` and `cos` start repeating)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Sorry, thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're pushing an `array` here: `n.push([x,y])` you can access the x component of the first element with `n[0][0]` and the y component of the same element with `n[0][1]`

Example:

```
var n = [];
n.push( ["x", "y"] );
console.log( n[0][0] );
console.log( n[0][1] );
```

As for the useful values of `t` - in the image you've shown, you'll notice that the same butterfly is drawn several times at different sizes. To draw a complete butterfly, you need to use the range for t of [0..2pi]. If you want to draw two butterflies, you need to use the range [0..4pi]. That is it's cyclic over the same period that a circle is. Unlike a circle however, each cycle doesn't draw over the previous one.

Here's a quick and nasty example:

```js
function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt) {
  butterFly();
}

function butterFly() {
  var pointArray = [];
  var stepSize = 0.05; // ~125 steps for every 360°
  var upperLimit = 4 * Math.PI;
  var scale = 20;
  for (var t = 0.0; t < upperLimit; t += stepSize) {
    var xVal = Math.sin(t) * ((Math.exp(Math.cos(t))) - (2 * Math.cos(4 * t)) - (Math.pow(Math.sin(t / 12), 5)));
    var yVal = Math.cos(t) * ((Math.exp(Math.cos(t))) - (2 * Math.cos(4 * t)) - (Math.pow(Math.sin(t / 12), 5)));
    pointArray.push([scale * xVal, -scale * yVal]); // -1 value since screen-y direction is opposite direction to cartesian coords y
  }
  drawButterFly(pointArray);
}

function drawButterFly(pointArray) {
  var can = byId('myCan');
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  var originX, originY;
  originX = can.width / 2;
  originY = can.height / 2;

  ctx.beginPath();
  for (var i = 0; i < pointArray.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      ctx.moveTo(originX + pointArray[i][0], originX + pointArray[i][1]);
    } else {
      ctx.lineTo(originX + pointArray[i][0], originY + pointArray[i][1]);
    }
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='myCan' width='256' height='256' />
```

Comment: I changed the program over to a stack snippet. Might be pointless since you included the output. Feel free to roll back the edit.

Comment: No, not at all. It's better, I think. The pic was only about 10kb - the text even smaller. If people want the output, they can use their resources to compute it, rather than SOs to download it. Good move! I'll remove the image.

Comment: How did you conclude to the upperlimit being 4*PI?

Comment: @user3590212 - I just took a punt and guessed that it was periodic like a circle is. So I tried an upper limit of 2pi - this gave me one iteration. I then changed it to 4 and voila! I then thought more closely about it and thought hang-on! It uses trig functions - of _course_ it's periodic over the same interval as a circle.

Comment: @enhzflep are you sure that it's periodic over 4*Pi? `cos(t)` (and therefore `cos(4t)`) certainly is, but `sin(t/12)` doesn't repeat until `t/12 = 2*Pi`, which implies `t = 24 * Pi` (I tested with the code snippets below & the graphs for `4*Pi` vs `24*Pi` look different)

Comment: @tanvanb - nope. I'm sure it's periodic over 2*Pi just like a circle. The first term of each equation is the one that makes this happen `Math.sin(t) *`  and `Math.cos(t) *`. The other terms are the ones responsible for the changing distance from the origin that each 2pi interval has as compared to the previous 2pi interval. Compare an image using the interval [0..4pi] with one of [0..24pi] - All the features of the first one are present in the second one - the second one simply has more instances of the butterfly. `tavnab's` animated solution shows this nicely.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, the Butterfly curve is given as a pair of parametric equations, meaning you increment `t` to get the next `(x, y)` points on your curve. In other words, your `t` is what you should be using in place of `u` in your code, and the range of values for t should be `0 .. 24*pi` as that's the range in which `sin(t / 12)` has its unique values).

Here's a version that demonstrates the drawing of the curve to a canvas:

```js
function getPoint(t, S, O) {
  var cos_t = Math.cos(t);
  var factor = Math.exp(cos_t) - 2 * Math.cos(4*t) - Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12), 5);
  return {
    x: S * Math.sin(t) * factor + O.x,
    y: S * cos_t * factor + O.y
  };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// First path
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';

var offset = {x:150, y:120};
var scale = 40;
var maxT = 24 * Math.PI;

var p = getPoint(0, scale, offset);
ctx.moveTo(p.x, canvas.height - p.y);
for (var t = 0.01; t <= maxT; t += 0.01) {
  p = getPoint(t, scale, offset);
  ctx.lineTo(p.x, canvas.height - p.y);
}
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
#c {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

One thing to note: canvases have `y = 0` start at the top, so you need to inverse your y (i.e. `canvas.height - y`) to have your curve orient correctly.

### UPDATE: Added animated version

As requested by royhowie, here's an animated version, using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame):

```js
function getPoint(t, S, O) {
  var cos_t = Math.cos(t);
  var factor = Math.exp(cos_t) - 2 * Math.cos(4*t) - Math.pow(Math.sin(t/12), 5);
  return {
    x: S * Math.sin(t) * factor + O.x,
    y: S * cos_t * factor + O.y
  };
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var offset = {x:150, y:120};
var scale = 40;
var maxT = 24 * Math.PI;

var animationID;
var started = false;
var t = 0;

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!started) {
    animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    started = true;
  }
});

document.getElementById('pause').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (started) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(animationID);
    started = false;
  }
});



function animate() {
  animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  
  var p = getPoint(t, scale, offset);

  if (t === 0) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.moveTo(p.x, canvas.height - p.y);
    t += 0.01;
  } else if (t < maxT) {
    ctx.lineTo(p.x, canvas.height - p.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    t += 0.01;
  } else {
    cancelAnimationFrame(animationID);
  }
}
```

```css
#c {
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="pause">Pause</button>
</div>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Challenge: animate the drawing of the curve. ([`window.requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame))

Comment: @royhowie - good one. I was just noticing the different approach taken and wondering of the benefits other than reduced memory consumption. You've just nailed the other (bigger?) one.

Comment: @enhzflep I think the animation can be done easily with recursion, similar to how I [draw a maze](http://royhowie.com/script/maze.js) on my website.

Comment: @tavnab - great work! Too bad I can only vote for your answer once. The animation alone deserves one, I think.

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1**

For an arbitrary integer `i`, let `n[i] = [xi, yi]`.  `xi` can then be accessed via `n[i][0]` and `yi` via `n[i][1]`

**Question 2**

For values of `t`, I am sure you're gonna want to use sub-integer values, so I recommend using a constant increment value representing the "resolution" of your graph.

Let's call it `dt`.  Also, I'd advise changing your variable names from single letters to something more descriptive, like `min_t` and `max_t`, and instead of `n` I'm going to call your array `points.`

```
function drawButterFly(points){
    for (var i = 0, n = points.count; i < n; ++i) {
        var x = points[i][0];
        var y = points[i][1];
        ...
    }
}

function butterFly(min_t, max_t, dt, r) {

    var points = [];
    for (var t = min_t; t < max_t; t+=dt){
        var x = r*Math.sin(t)*...
        var y = r*Math.cos(t)*...
        points.push([x,y]);
    }
    drawButterFly(points, dt);
}
```

I'm not sure what the other loop inside of that function was for, but if you need it, you can adapt from the pattern above.

Usage example: `butterFly(0, 10, 0.01, 3)` -> `t` goes from `0` to `10` with an increment of `0.01`, and `r=3`

Comment: You can't use the `^` symbol in place of the pow function. If you want 2.5³, you write `Math.pow(2.5,3)`, not `2.5^3`.

Comment: So true! I didn't even see that.  Edited it out.  Good catch.

Comment: No worries. Good point you make also with regards to the names of variables. We all changed them, but only you made a point out mentioning having done so.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question it's a better option to replace the multidimensional array containing the `x` and `y` coordinates with an object. Then when iterating over the array you can check for the object values.

So instead of:

```
n.push([x,y]);
```

you should do:

```
m.push({
    'xPos' : x,
    'yPos' : y
})
```

Later you can access this by `m.xPos` or `m.yPos`
Then you can access the x and y values by object literal names.

Regarding the second question: for a good pseudo code implementation of butterfly curves you might check Paul Burke site: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/butterfly/. So `t` in your case is:

```
t = i * 24.0 * PI / N;
```

As you see `t` is a parametric value which got incremented on each step when iterating over the array.

Comment: Wouldn't you actually be able to access the individual components with `m[index].xPos` and `m[index].yPos`? - That is to say, `m` is an array of objects with these attributes. `m.xPos` and `m.yPos` in your example would be undefined. Furthermore, you could even remove the single-quotes from the object definition, `m.push( {'xPos': x, 'yPos': y} )` is equivalent to `m.push( {xPos: x, yPos: y} )`

Comment: Yes, you can but it think much more elegant to access object properties and not array indexes. Maybe in terms of performance is slower.

Comment: No, you're missing my point. You're using an array of objects. `m` is the array itself - it doesn't have the xPos or yPos members, _the objects contained in this array do_ - You approach necessitates using both array indices and object properties, that's fine - it's a matter of taste. The point is however, that the following statement in your answer is incorrect. `Later you can access this by m.xPos or m.yPos Then you can access the x and y values by object literal names.` Type the following into your console:  `var m=[]; m.push( {xPos:'x',yPos:'y'} ); console.log( m.xPos );` Understand now?

Comment: Yes, but the idea is that when you iterate over the array, you get the object from array index `i`, and at that  moment you have access to object's `x` and `y` properties. That's what i'm talking about.

Comment: Sure, but that's not what your answer says. Compilers and script interpreters don't care for such imprecision. Why not update your answer to include this method of use - to make your answer accurate instead? Just add a small block showing the iteration over such an array - at least your answer would add something then. As it stands, it is incorrect and you've posted misinformation. I'll edit it myself if you'd prefer not to. :)