# How to animate the drawing of a spiral

Tags: javascript, canvas, requestanimationframe, spiral

Hi i have the following code that generates a spiral on a canvas, what I want is for the spiral to be animated as it is drawn, at this moment with below code, the spiral is fully drawn when the page loads. I want to see the spiral being drawn. I would like to use requestAnimationFrame to do the job.

my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Spiral</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my Javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.moveTo(centerX,centerY);


    var gap =2;
    var steps = 60;

    var increment = 2*Math.PI/steps;
    var theta = increment;

while(theta < 20*Math.PI) {
    var newX = centerX + theta * Math.cos(theta) * gap;
    var newY = centerY + theta * Math.sin(theta) * gap;
    ctx.lineTo(newX,newY);
    theta = theta + increment;
}
ctx.stroke();
```

please see for jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gustav1105/hx8tm43k/

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096766/creating-the-butterfly-curve-with-arrays Particularly, pay attention to `tavnab's` answer, which provides both a static and an animated version. (of an entirely different curve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the animation to draw the spiral over a given time span (e.g. 4 seconds). I placed your drawing code inside an update() function. I called the requestAnimationFrame function with the update() function. The first time the update() function is called, I record the start time of the animation. I then compute the drawing progress (0 = start, 1 = end) by subtracting current timeStamp from start time and then dividing by desired total time (e.g. 4 seconds = 4000 ms). I then draw the spiral up to the current progress. If spiral is not complete (i.e. progress < 1) then a call requestAnimationFrame() function again.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var gap = 2;
var steps = 60;
var increment = 2 * Math.PI / steps;
var start = null;
function update(timeStamp) {
    if (!start) {
        start = timeStamp;
    }
    var progress = Math.min((timeStamp - start) / 4000, 1);
    var theta = increment;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.moveTo(centerX,centerY);
    while (theta < progress * 20 * Math.PI) {
        var newX = centerX + theta * Math.cos(theta) * gap;
        var newY = centerY + theta * Math.sin(theta) * gap;
        ctx.lineTo(newX,newY);
        theta = theta + increment;
    }
    ctx.stroke();
    if (progress < 1) {
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
    }
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

To animate use `window.requestAnimationFrame(yourFunction);` this will call your function synced to the screen and in step with the browser to provide the best possible animation performance. It will also pass the function it calls the current time in millisecond.

I have just added an `update` function that clears the screen. Then calls your spiral with a small mod to animate it according to the time. Then the update function requests a new frame and exits.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
function drawSpiral(time) {
    var angOff, gap, steps, increment, theta, newX, newY;
    // use time to get an angle offset
    angOff = time / -60;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
    gap = 2;
    steps = 60;
    increment = 2 * Math.PI / steps;
    theta = increment;
    while (theta < 20 * Math.PI) {
        newX = centerX + theta * Math.cos(theta + angOff) * gap;
        newY = centerY + theta * Math.sin(theta + angOff) * gap;
        ctx.lineTo(newX, newY);
        theta = theta + increment;
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
function update(time) { // called by browser through requestAnimationFrame
    // time is the current time in milliseconds

    // clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // draw the spiral animating via the time
    drawSpiral(time);

    // this gets the next animation frame
    // that is in sync with the browsers rendering and
    // will keep in sync with the screen refresh so you dont
    // get any shearing
    requestAnimationFrame(update); //' request next animation frame
}
// start the animation
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
 <canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```